com.google.android.play:core has added this note for core:1.8.0 - but app version is very old in email
Recently I got this message from google:
com.google.android.play:core has added this note for core:1.8.0:

Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration


You may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK version to production or open testing.

Affected app bundles and APKs:
version: 4194526 (2.0.220729)
In the last part it mention my app version from 2022 and since then I updated app multiple times and last version is from 2024.
I checked android project dependencies and only reference is this:
+--- project :react-native-rate
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.67.5 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2

If I see right here this version is fine.
Is there a reason why in mail old app version is mentioned and should I be worried about this?
My app build.gradle config is:
buildscript {
    ext {
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        appCompatVersion = "1.1.0"
        supportV4Version = "1.0.0"
        mediaCompatVersion = "1.0.1"
        googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "19.0.1"
        facebookSdkVersion = "13.1.0"
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    }


UPDATE


checkout this - https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration

I have faced similar issue this month. Can you check the bundle version code 4194526 which you uploaded few years back must be still active now in any of the testing track like closed open alpha or you have not done 100% rollout of production latest version. Updating the track with latest version or doing rollout to 100% will fix this warning ⚠️

@BobSmith you are right it is really in "Open Testing" https://i.sstatic.net/nBVLXgPN.png but I don't have option to remove it do you know how to do that (is it possible)?

@1110 Please read my previous comment again in "Open Testing" you can Update the track with latest version will solve this problem.

Put answer please so I can reward it. Thank you

@1110 Let me answer it with all the steps and screenshots required so that if in future someone else face the issue will get solution without wasting time like me (2 days).

I have faced similar issue this month. Can you check the bundle

Version code 4194526
Version name 2.0.220729

Which you uploaded few years back must be still active now in any of the testing track like closed open alpha or you have not done 100% rollout of production latest version.
Short Answer

Updating the track with latest version or doing rollout to 100% will fix this warning ⚠️


TL;DR
Below are the steps to do the same :
1. Open Track
Which latest version match with the google email's version code

2. Update to latest version

Click on Create new release button

Choose option Add from library



3. Select from list of versions
Tick on the checkbox shown on the left.

Press Add to release button.
4. Press Next button

On left side Toast will be shown for successful selection.



Then Press Next

5. Last Step

Scroll down to bottom.
Check the rollout percentage
Make it 100%



Important Note :
After that app will go in-review which generally takes few hours 2-3 by max for old apps and testing tracks. For new apps and productions track it will take max of 7 Days. If your app is still in review after 7 days you may contact google support.


https://support.google.com/googleplay/?hl=en#topic=3364260

